# Very Hard Integral with trigonometric, logarithim and hyperbolic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've just found a pretty difficult integral. 
$\int { \tan { x\sqrt { \frac { 72\cos ^{ 4 }{ x } -40\cos { 2x } -32 }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ x } -\cos { 2x } +2\tan ^{ 2 }{ x } +3\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  } \cosh { \left( \ln { \sqrt { \cos ^{ 4 }{ x } -4\cos { x } +3 } +\tanh ^{ -1 }{ \left( 3\cos { x }  \right) -\tanh ^{ -1 }{ \left(\cos{x}\right)}}}\right)}}}dx$
I think that the best substitution in this case could be u=cosx but I'm not able to simplify the integral.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337475/difficult-integral-involving-trigonometric-and-hypertrigonometric-functions/3337559#3337559) for a strategy to try first before any u-subs

Comment: You can simplify by noting that $\cosh\log\phi=\frac{\phi+\phi^{-1}}{2}.$ Also, I can see many trigonometric simplifications here waiting to be done -- Have you actually written something down? Furthermore, I'm pretty sure the inverse hyperbolic tangents also simplify, etc.